# Ubuntu on hdd won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm new to Ubuntu, had it for fews weeks alongside Windows and now I want to make Ubuntu my only OS.

Originally I had Windows installed on my SSD and Ubuntu on my HDD. As I formatted my SSD, I thought it wouldn't interfere with Ubuntu, but it won't boot anymore.

My question is: did I mess with GRUB and now I should make a recovery with an Ubuntu installation media? Can I install and boot Ubuntu on my SSD using an Ubuntu installation media without having to fix anything else?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This might be a poor question, however they made a genuine mistake (by not understanding where grub was initially installed) and it was answered in a comment. So, it doesn't need clarity and it does belong on this site because it was solved with ref to a Ubuntu help page. It should be kept (imho) possibly flagged as answered so that it doesn't remain opened, but retained for future reading.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with boot-repair as suggested by [@oldfred](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/145882/oldfred) in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681504/ubuntu-on-hdd-wont-boot/683988#comment1287898_681504):

> Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install, not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10) help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair –
> oldfred

Comment: Please mark your answer as the accepted answer using the green tick icon next to the answer.